# Magento Plugin for New Passwords

Tags: plugin, magento2.4.2, change-password

Is there any magento plugin that allows in the section of "password change" to restict the field "new password" not to accept values as in "current password"?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this module, but it looks simple and effective. It's only two years old and has been tested against 2.3.5. I glanced over the code quickly, and didn't see any reason it wouldn't work in 2.4.x; but I suppose you'd have to try it to see.

https://github.com/kirchbergerknorr/magento2-module-password-history

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add observer before/after controller dispatch

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpassword">
        <observer name="restrict_password" instance="Gohil\Rajesh\Model\RestrictWebsite" />
    </event>
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_resetpasswordpost">
        <observer name="restrict_password" instance="Gohil\Rajesh\Model\RestrictWebsite" />
    </event>
</config>
```